# Outlook delegate meeting acceptance issue

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In outlook, my boss has designated me as a delegate. I accept/decline any meeting requests sent to her. The issue we are having is....she doesn't know if I accepted it or not because it shows her name. How can I get it to say I accepted on her behalf, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would perform accepting/rejecting using command **Edit the response before sending**.
There you can:

- Put your boss to **Cc** field so she receives your acceptation/rejection response as well.

and

1. Insert your name at the beginning of the message body, e.g. `--by Olivia--`
2. Assign (let's say) Blue category to such a request so your boss will know it easily from the category.

Use option 1 if meeting organizer has to explicitly learn it was done by you. Use option 2 if visual cue is enough for your boss. Or use both.

Note: option 2 will most likely send the blue category also to the meeting organizer. They can create a rule to clear categories when a message is received in case if seeing a category assigned to the message is annoying to them.